# I do not understand nuget versioning

Tags: nuget

A picture to illustrate:

[image: nuget versions]

According to Nuget, the latest version is 4.3.0
It is apparently the one I have installed as well.

but when I check the properties of the dll I have, it shows version 4.0.2.0

why is this happening?

Comment: nuget versions don't always relate to the assembly version, you often see nuget version x.x.x then an assembly version of 1.0.0

Comment: ahhh, ok, so the package version and the assembly version are not related then. thanks!

Comment: They're sometimes aligned by it's project by project basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nuget versions don't always relate to the assembly version, you often see nuget version x.x.x then an assembly version of 1.0.0

There is no rule to this so it's on a package by package basis, also a package could also contain multiple assemblies at different version too!